# Android CollapsingToolbarLayout setLayoutFlags of views inside

Tags: android, scroll, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I'm trying to make a `CollapsingToolbarLayout` that is like GooglePlay .
All is fine except for one thing. 
I can't make the `toolbar` inside `CollapsingToolbarLayout` to `alwaysEnter`

```
<android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
                android:elevation="2dp"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed|snap"
                app:contentScrim="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                app:titleEnabled="false"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <ImageView
                    app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                    android:maxHeight="300dp"
                    android:id="@+id/profileFarmImage_loggedLO"
                    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"/>

                <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|snap"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                    app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

            </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
```

I know that setting `scrollFlags` inside `CollapsingToolbarLayout` won't have any effect, but if I set the `scrollFlags`of my `CollapsingToolbarLayout` as `enterAlwaysCollapsed` I get unwanted behavior in which when the screen is scrolled to bottom and when I scrollup again all the views inside `CollapsingToolbarLayout` is shown. That's not the behavior I want.
 The behavior I want is when the screen is scrolled to bottom then when I scroll up I only want the `toolbar` to show and when the screen is scrolled to top only then it will show the remaining view inside `CollapsingToolbarLayout`.

I know that this behavior is possible since GooglePlay implements it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix it by setting `CollapsingToolbarLayout`

```
android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
```